# Asp.net MVC routing: default values before static - why it doesn't work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

For example, I want to be able to get my login page as by `/login` and by `/en/login` route.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "LoginLang",
            url: "{lang}/Login",
            defaults: new { lang = "en", controller = "Account", action = "Login" }
            );
```

But if `/en/login` gets accepted, route `/login` is not. It is treatable by an additional route, but still, do you have explanation why `/login` gets rejected?

Answer (score 2):

Because your route pattern says the lang (parameter) string should be before the string "Login" in the url.

If you want to support both `en/login` and `login`, you should create one more route entry and register it in the route table.

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "DefaultLoginLang",
   url: "Login",
   defaults: new { lang = "en", controller = "Account", action = "Login" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
   name: "LoginLang",
   url: "{lang}/Login",
   defaults: new { lang = "en", controller = "Account", action = "Login" }
);
// Your default route registration goes here
```

Or you can use attribute routing

```
[Route("Login")]
[Route("{lang}/Login")]
public ActionResult Login(string lang="en")
{
   //to do : return something
}
```